Container border color doesn't bend in with the background color
Okay so I have this small container on top of another container. All of this is in a Stack widget. Even thought both container has same color value of White. The upper small container border has faint black border as you can see in the picture if you focus enough. Like it's not perfectly bending in. Is there any way to fix this?
The smaller container code
Container(

  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 67, 83, 114),
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13)
    ),
    child: Text(
      duration,
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 13),
    ),
),

The background Container code:
Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
    width: 195,
    height: 180,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
      color: Colors.white,
      boxShadow: const [
        BoxShadow(
          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 194, 221, 245),
          offset: Offset(0, 6),
          blurRadius: 5,
        )
      ]),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        ClipRRect(
          // image
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          child: Image.asset(
            imagePath,
            width: 185,
            height: 120,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
),


Close up picture


Share an image of your output that you have tried.
Or if this is a tried output share the actual image you want to create.

Add strokeAlign:0 to smaller container. You can check out below code.
Container(

  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 67, 83, 114),
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2, strokeAlign: 0),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13)
    ),
    child: Text(
      duration,
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 13),
    ),
),



  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 67, 83, 114),
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2, strokeAlign: 0),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13)
    ),
    child: Text(
      duration,
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 13),
    ),
),


Try adding strokeAlign:0 to the upper small container border.
